# Object not defined when using await

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, passport.js

I am currently trying to add some authentication to my node API.

Right now I'm using PassportJS (pretty new to this so sorry for my incompetents).

I am trying to add a local strategy and check if the users password is legit when loggin in:

```
// Local Strategy
passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(async (username, password, done) => {
    try {
      // Find user by username
      const user = await User.findOne({ username })

      // No user found
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false)
      }
      console.log('user', user) // Getting output

      // Check if password correct
      const isMatch = await user.isValidPassword(password)

      // Handle if password is not correct
      if (!isMatch) {
        return done(null, false)
      }

      // Return user
      done(null, user)
    } catch (err) {
      done(err, false)
    }
  })
)
```

Something I've noticed is when using `await` on `const isMatch = await user.isValidPassword(password)` Postman is saying: `Error: ReferenceError: user is not defined`. And when I remove `await` it works fine, but I can type in the wrong password but I still can login. And I can see my `user` object when I console.log it.

```
{
    "username": "martinnord3",
    "password": "this_is_the_wrong_password"
}
```

Here's the `isValidPassword` function:

```
UserSchema.methods.isValidPassword = async function(newPassword) {
  try {
    return await bcrypt.compare(newPassword, user.password)
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err)
  }
}
```

I guess there's something obvious I'm missing, but I can't manage to solve this.

Thanks for taking your time to read this!

Comment: What does `user.isValidPassword(password)` returns? Try without await.

Comment: @Firanolfind Hello! What do you mean with returns? :O

Answer (score 1):

Well this is a bit awkward, but I guess it's my duty to answer my own dumb question... My function `isValidPassword` has this: `...user.password` and I don't specify what `user` is in that function.. It expects `this`.